# Google CloudML job fails with "CreateSession still waiting for response from worker"

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

It's intermittent and seemingly non-deterministic: the exact same job will sometimes work perfectly, sometimes it will stall and print dozens of these errors, then work, and sometimes it stalls for a long time, then dies.

Other StackOverflow users who have run into this say it's a bad Cluster config (typically wrong port #s), but we're not setting any cluster params, instead relying on tf.contrib.learn.Experiment to do all the distributed config.  Also if it were just a bad config, then it would either always work, or never work.

Full error looks like:

> 10:53:28.899 2017-10-20 17:53:28.899466: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/master.cc:209] CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:ps/replica:0/task:0

Comment: Can you provide info about what scale tier (or, if custom, how many replicas and what machine types)?

Comment: Also which estimator you are using (is it custom)?

Comment: Using STANDARD_1 tier.  It's a custom estimator for our particular model.

Comment: This error usually means the indicated worker has not come up yet. Do you have any information about how frequent this scenario is and how long it takes until it dies (in those cases)?

Comment: It takes from 4-10 minutes to die.  The problem is intermittent lasting a few hours (typically during PST working hours) during which no jobs will run,  but has only been happening the past week or so.

Comment: We also see this message in job status: 
>The replica ps 1 exited with a non-zero status of 128. Termination reason: ContainerCannotRun. The replica ps 2 exited with a non-zero status of 128. Termination reason: ContainerCannotRun. To find out more about why your job exited please check the logs:
However, there are no logs for the PS servers, nor any errors in the other logs except the CreateSession message.

Comment: Thanks for the info. This merits some debugging. Can you send the name of your project and one or more jobs that are failing to cloudml-feedback@google.com?

Comment: Thanks, sent an email to cloudml-feedback and also mentioned your StackOverflow handle.